# How to do gmail search box alike with angular material?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using material with angular v9/v8. And I want to do component just like gmail search box did. same behavior: when I click on the right button near the input field, a div/panel with is appear below. (not matter for me what this div contain).

[image]

So I think to do it with matInput and matMenu. but it don't come out as I expected.

- The div is closing the I click on it.
- Not open below the textbox (it open under the input), doesn't keep the width of input.

How do I fix with angular material?

```
<mat-form-field class="example-form-field">
  <mat-label>Search</mat-label>
  <input matInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="value">
  <button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" mat-button *ngIf="value" matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear">
    <mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
  </button>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" >
  <form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <mat-label>Company (disabled)</mat-label>
    <input matInput disabled value="Google">
  </mat-form-field>

  <table class="example-full-width" cellspacing="0"><tr>
    <td><mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <mat-label>First name</mat-label>
      <input matInput>
    </mat-form-field></td>
    <td><mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <mat-label>Long Last Name That Will Be Truncated</mat-label>
      <input matInput>
    </mat-form-field></td>
  </tr></table>

  <p>
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <mat-label>Address</mat-label>
      <textarea matInput placeholder="Ex. 100 Main St">1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy</textarea>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <mat-label>Address 2</mat-label>
      <textarea matInput></textarea>
    </mat-form-field>
  </p>
</form>
</mat-menu>
```

Comment: Something like autocomplete?

Comment: yes, but again in autocomplete I face the same problem. and I want to open the panel only in the button, not when I click on the textbox.

Comment: You should checkout CDK overlay: https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview. Specifically, you'll need `ConnectedPositionStrategy`. And you can control the creation on your own.

Comment: @JonSud Did you find any solution for this design, i know its been long time if you did it then you might not even remember it, but just want to check in case